# Server-based password management tool

Tags: passwords, password-management

I've been using KeePassX for password storage for a long time, however, now I have some specific needs it can't handle. So I'm looking for a tool that can do this:

1. Runs as server-side application storing all my passwords on the server. Would be best if it was PHP based so hosting could be cheap. Another option is it being FTP based storage (saves encrypted password file on predefined FTP server while client is local).
2. Can be reached through a generic browser (desktop or smartphone based). Browser asks me for my master password/keyfile and gives me stored passwords.
3. Has most of KeePassX functionality: groups of passwords, icons, password generator, etc.

Is there any tool like what I described out there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Dashlane](https://www.dashlane.com/), they package that solution pretty much as you say.

Another option would be to look at using KeePass with DropBox, but KeePassX doesn't support this so you'd need to look at using KeePass2 from keepass.info for the desktop application and MiniKeePass for on mobile. Problem with this is that KeePass2 runs horrible on Mac, so if that is your platform of choice then this is probably out.